# In Android web browser dismiss keyboard on html input element focus

Tags: android, jquery, html

Here what I have:
- I load html page on Android Browser;
- when I choose SELECT DATE the input element with a type="text" gets focus and using jQuery loads the a date picker;
- but as a side effect of getting focus I get Android keyboard shown;

How can I dismiss the keyboard but at the same keeping focus on this input element with a type="text"?

There are some requirements:
1) there logic has to be configured in html page (I mean not on Android device, but of html, js or css);
2) input field can't be hidden, disabled or taken away (it will take away date picker);

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the short and sharp solution:

- add to this input element new attribute: readonly="readonly"
  so finally my input element will look like:

  < input type="text" id="datepicker" **readonly="readonly"** ... >

it will show jQuery date picker and at the same time it will not trigger Android device keyboard to show;

Hope it will be helpful for somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

Add `onfocus="blur();"` in text field.

For example,

```
<input type="text" name="exapmle" onfocus="blur();">
```